# Does NSURLSessionDataTask get paused on background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to know about the behaviour of NSURLSessionDataTask in background.

Does NSURLSessionDataTask get paused right away (as soon as the app enters background)? or does iOS give some time hopefully 30 seconds or so until the response ?

Comment: I would recommend to start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW1) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondatatask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You will not continue with `NSURLSessionDataTask` in background mode with `defaultSessionConfiguration`  !

If you want to continue execution in background then you need to configure session with `backgroundSessionConfiguration`.

When you are using  `backgroundSessionConfiguration` you can't send `data` directly to server, you have to give file url and from that url you have to send bytes or chunks to server, and you have to use `uploadTask` or `downloadTask` with `backgroundSessionConfiguration`!!

If you wants little time after entering in background then you can use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`. These are very huge concepts to explain every thing here, It's better that you read documentations from apple or some tutorial for that!!! You should refer [Apple Documentation for Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) and [Apple documentation for NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) !

Comment: Does it pause as soon as it enters background ?

Comment: yeah, If you haven't set any kind of continue background execution then yes!

Comment: Thanks You ! I was specified in the docs explicitly , so I wanted to make sure.